# Set property of another UIViewController

Tags: ios, properties, uiviewcontroller, parameter-passing

In my DetailViewController.h I've declared the property * type as seen below:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *type;
@end
```

Then I got a ListViewController which is a UIViewController containing a TableView. 
The ListViewController.h looks like this:

```
@interface ListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

In my ListViewController.m I want to change the value of * type a soon I switch the View (view switching is working fine).

I'm doing this by adding the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UINavigationController * navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];
    DetailViewController * detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    detailController.type = @"video";

    NSLog(@"Type: %@", detailController.type);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
}
```

When I put a breakpoint at the second line in this block/function I get detailController with in it * type.
When I NSLog this a few lines later it return "(null)".
The View is changed but but the type is not set.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?
Someone who has a solution for this or can point me to something we're this is explained?

Because I tried searching for the answer but I couldn't find anything equivalent to my problem, or I used the wrong search terms..

Comment: are you sure detailController is not nil?

Comment: If I NSLog detailController between line 2 - 4 in this block/function it returns "<DetailViewController: 0x14e93e40>".

Comment: have you overridden your setter for type?

Comment: You are pushing the `UINavigationController *navigationController` into the navigation stack not your `detailController`. The reference to the `detailController` gets lost (or even leaks if not under ARC) after returning from the method.

Comment: The problem is that you create a new DetailViewController; (DetailViewController * detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init]), but you push UINavigationController. What you should do is to instatintia DetailViewController from the storyboard and push its instance. Btw, pushing NavigationViewController is generally a bad pracitse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method change the following lines`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailViewController * detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];;

    detailController.type = @"video";

    NSLog(@"Type: %@", detailController.type);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailController animated:YES];
}`
```

in your storyboard select `DetailViewController` and give storyboard id as "DetailController". Make sure your `ListViewController` is embed in `UINavigationController`, you can do that by selecting `ListViewController` and go to `editor->Embed in->Navigation Controller`. Follow these steps and your problem will be solved.

OR you can give segue from your ListViewController to DetailViewController and use

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; //create tableview outlet
    [segue.destinationViewController setType:@"video"];
}
```

Comment: Awesome this solved my problem! Afterwards such a stupid mistake haha! I already got it nested in a NavigationController and everything works fine now. I first tried adding a Segue to all my Cells but then my whole app crashed cause DetailViewController lost his navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

What is this for?

```
UINavigationController * navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];
```

Why are you pushing a navigation controller inside a navigation controller?

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

`detailController` was not used or displayed.

Try this instead:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the last line - you are telling the nav controller to push itself!

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController * detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailController"];

    detailController.type = @"video";

    NSLog(@"Type: %@", detailController.type);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the navigation controller and the alloc-init method both instantiates the save view controller??

If yes, try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
DetailViewController * detailController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

detailController.type = @"video";

NSLog(@"Type: %@", detailController.type);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```